# Recover deleted MySQL rows?

Tags: mysql, recover

The situation is that I deleted rows from the database and now they are wanted back.

There are no binary logs, and no backup.

But as I know records are not deleted instantly, they're just marked as 'deleted', but they're actually deleted only after next optimisation.

And I have just copied all the database files into safe places: frms, MIYs and MYDs. I know the structure of table I'm interested in; I can even find all deleted row ids.

Is there any tool to recover recently deleted rows?

Comment: Remember that MySQL is transactional - you may use set autocommit=0; (and should!) before all DELETES and UPDATES (and even INSERTS). This allows you to do a SELECT to make sure the proper end results. If there was a problem then you can do a ROLLBACK. Sorry for the loss of data. Tough way to learn a lesson. Hope this helps avoid it in the future.

Comment: @NatetheNoob This is TRUE for InnoDB only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to know the offset of the data (or know some unique string) for the rows you deleted, then go ahead an pop open a hex editor and copy the (binary) data by hand. If you **do** recover it all you'll be extremely fortunate, and I hope you write up an article on it, because frankly I don't believe this is possible.